# There is an error when insert two activity in activity

Tags: android

In my MounthActivity, there are two activities.

First is MonthChart and second is Test.

My code is following :

```
package com.h.callsta;

    import android.app.ActivityGroup;
    import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MonthActivity extends ActivityGroup{

    private LinearLayout lo1, lo2;   

       LocalActivityManager lam = getLocalActivityManager();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_month);
    lo1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lo1);  
    lo2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lo2);
    start_activity();

      }

public void start_activity(){

   Window win1 = lam.startActivity("0",new Intent(MonthActivity.this, MonthChart.class));
   View view1 = win1.getDecorView();
   lo1.addView(view1);  
   Window win2 = lam.startActivity("1",new Intent(MonthActivity.this, test.class));
   View view2 = win2.getDecorView();
   lo2.addView(view2);

     }


}
```

when run is only shows `MonthChart`,and the `test`didn't

But if I change the order of them, that Test activity will be first and MonthChart will be second, and they became visible properly, Why?

I guess it is because the MonthChart is too long ,is it?

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) concept they are easily multiple acitvites you can use

Comment: oh the fragment,Would you please provide an example?thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

`startActivity` will only show the Activity that is in the top of the [Activity Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). therefor calling the `Activity.startActivity` method will show only one of them.

what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: can i show both activity at the same time without move the position?

Comment: as altaf said, this is the job of a Fragment